# Code error 2104 after moving aspx page to some folder

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I get the following error after moving aspx page to some folder.

```
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
```

**Environment:** Win7 x64, VS2010, SL 4.0.50524.0, IE8, IIS7.5

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. In VS 2010 create a new Silverlight
   Application (target .NET Framework
   4.0).
2. Host the Silverlight application (Silverlight version 4.0) in a new Web site (Web application project).
3. Runs SilverlightApplication.web project, where the starting page is SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx
4. Application run successful without any error.
5. In VS2010, create a new folder with name Test under SilverlightApplication.web project and move the SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx page to it.

   SilverlightApplication.web
   -- Test
      -- SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx
6. In the SilverlightApplication.web project change the path to the starting page refer to the moved pageSilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx (Properties -> Web tab -> Start Action -> Specific Page = Test/SilverlightApplication5TestPage.aspx)
7. Runs  SilverlightApplication.web project again.

**Result:**
The above JS error appears.

I have checked the MIME types (xaml, xap and etc.) in my IIS. They are present.
I can successfully access directly to the SilverlightApplication.xap file.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Maybe I should change some additional settings after moving asp page that host Silverlight control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same result when following your instructions. The problem is the following line in your aspx page:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/TestOnly.xap"/>
```

The page is trying to load the XAP file from a directory called ClientBin under your test directory. Change the line to this:

```
<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/TestOnly.xap"/>
```

Now the path will start at the root of the web site. I also noticed this line in the aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
```

This won't load correctly either for the same reason. I changed the line to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Silverlight.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Dave,

Thanks. That was the cause of my issue. After adding the "/" character to value and scr attribute the issue gas been resolved.

Best Regards, Oleg

Comment: Thanks. That was my issue to, adding the slash "/" to atr. value 
`<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/TestOnly.xap"/>`
the issue has been resolved.