# 403 - Forbidden: You do not have permission to view using the credentials that you supplied

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, http-status-code-403

After resolving some issues with deployment of my LightSwitch app to Azure, I was able to get the Azure Management Portal to report that everything was up and running fine. However when I try to access the site, I receive:

> Server Error
>
> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

This happens regardless of whether I have HTTPS required or not and regardless of the browser used. When this point is reached, no login has been presented and so no credentials have been supplied.

I can't see anything out of the ordinary in Fiddler that would cause this issue.

What should I been looking for to diagnose this problem?

---

Okay, it turns out that clicking on the `site.cloudapp.net` link like I used to be able to do causes a 403 Forbidden code. I now need to go to `site.cloudapp.net/DesktopClient` for some reason and then my site will appear.

Is there a specific reason for this change in behavior? Was there any sort of announcement? Is there any way to change it back to just `site.cloudapp.net`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths in various files needed to be changed.

In Web.config:

```xml
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="default.htm"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Needs to be:

```xml
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="DesktopClient/default.htm"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

In default.htm:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
```

Needs to be:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopClient/Silverlight.js"></script>
```

And:

```html
<param name="source" value="Web/ARIS2.DesktopClient.xap"/>
```

Needs to be:

```html
<param name="source" value="/DesktopClient/Web/ARIS2.DesktopClient.xap"/>
```

The front most slashes in the last two are important because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133168/code-error-2104-after-moving-aspx-page-to-some-folder/3137108#3137108).